# How to increase number of simultaneous websockets in IE 10?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, websocket

I have already written my web socket client program  which runs successfully in Firefox and Chrome. But I also have the requirement to make it work in IE 10. When I execute my program it gives me Security Error's.

I tried to investigate and I found that it's due to the number of connections I make in code is more then expected. Expected are 6 connections for IE 10. I can't reduce the number of connections as I have different sets of URL to be called.

Here it is how I make the connection:

```
var WS_serverstatus = window['MozWebSocket'] ? MozWebSocket : WebSocket
var svrstate=new WS_serverstatus("ws://"+'@{ play.Play.application().configuration().getString("engine.host") }'+":"+'@{ play.Play.application().configuration().getString("engine.port") }'+"/services/reports/v1/realtimestreaming/serverStatus")
```

Comment: Here's how signalr handles the issue: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/1744

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, this limit can only be fixed by changing a setting in the Windows registry:

> Internet Explorer 10. When enabled, the FEATURE_WEBSOCKET_MAXCONNECTIONSPERSERVER
>   feature sets the maximum
>   number of concurrent WebSocket connections allowed to a single host.
>   The minimum number that can be specified is 2 and the maximum value
>   allowed is 128.
>
> The default value for this setting is 6 in Internet
>   Explorer and applications hosting the WebBrowser Control. To modify
>   this feature by using the registry, add the name of your executable
>   file to the following setting.
>
> ...

([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330736%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#websocket_maxconn))

But it is suggested [here](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/849#issuecomment-23182744) that you could circumvent the limit by using a bunch of subdomains which all point to the same server.

Comment: I understad your suggestion but it will suit for application hitting different domain, thought i hv single server ith multiple connection. I can try the registry change and let see what happens.

Comment: I tried to find the registry entry you suggested ,but its not there. Do i neeed to add as new entery?

Comment: @Sohan sorry, I have no Windows-knowledge whatsoever so can't help you with that. As for the subdomains: you can have all those subdomains point to a single server/IP-address.

Comment: Ok thanks, the adding key to reg entry solution worked for me. I can mention as readme me instruction to users of IE.

Answer (score 2):

By looking at "Sohans" comment I though I should add this enhancement to "robertklep" answer.

- If you cannot find the "FEATURE_WEBSOCKET_MAXCONNECTIONSPERSERVER" registry entry you have to add this entry to the registry. Futher do not get confused with contoso.exe (that's what I got wrong) in the given link it has to be iexplore.exe.

I have attache the following image to eliminate all guess work.

[image]